# Error getting free alistar and free tristana

Tags: league-of-legends

I just create an account on youtube to get free alistar and an account on facebook to get free tristana.

- **Alistar Error:**

I already subscribed but everytime I try to generate the code it appears:
[image]

Then I click in that  button and appears:
[image]

And keeps doing that...

- **Tristana Error:**

I already liked LoL facebook page and after I click on my server:
[image]

Appears this message:
[image]

**Problem:**

What can I do to get them? I got free garen without problems, why do I have problems now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is around for more than a year now. Contact the [Riot Support](https://support.riotgames.com).

Note: there's also a free Garen with Dreadknight Skin on Twitter

Comment: Yes i know. I got him without any problem

Comment: that might be the case... however... it (still) is a problem on EUW